# How can I get text from a dynamic RadioButtonList?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I would like to know how to get the value or text of a RadioButtonList?

I'm using vb.net

Array is like this: `{ "apple", "banana", "dog" }`

My code (Dynamic RadioButtonList):

```
For Each x In radio
    If Not (x = ";") Then
        radio2 = radio2 & x
    Else
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(New ListItem(radio2))
        radio2 = ""
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What is your definition of "dynamic RadioButtonList"?

Comment: Dynamic is that the radiobutton data is not always the same, it gets the data from a database @Mr.Tripodi